# LeetCode: Divide Array in Sets of K Consecutive Numbers C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, hash-map

https://leetcode.com/problems/divide-array-in-sets-of-k-consecutive-numbers/

> Given an array of integers nums and a positive integer k, find whether
>   it's possible to divide this array into sets of k consecutive numbers
>   Return True if its possible otherwise return False.
>
> ```
> Example 1:
>
> Input: nums = [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6], k = 4
> Output: true
> Explanation: Array can be divided into [1,2,3,4] and [3,4,5,6].
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: nums = [3,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,9,10,11], k = 3
> Output: true
> Explanation: Array can be divided into [1,2,3] , [2,3,4] , [3,4,5] and [9,10,11].
>
> Example 3:
>
> Input: nums = [3,3,2,2,1,1], k = 3
> Output: true
>
> Example 4:
>
> Input: nums = [1,2,3,4], k = 3
> Output: false
> Explanation: Each array should be divided in subarrays of size 3.
>
>
>
> Constraints:
>
> 1 <= nums.length <= 10^5
> 1 <= nums[i] <= 10^9
> 1 <= k <= nums.length
> ```

Please review for performance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/divide-array-in-sets-of-k-consecutive-numbers/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class DivideArrayinSetsofKConsecutiveNumbersTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestExample()
        {
            int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6};
            int k = 4;
            Assert.IsTrue(DivideArrayinSetsofKConsecutiveNumbers.IsPossibleDivide(nums, k));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestFailed()
        {
            int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3,4};
            int k = 3;
            Assert.IsFalse(DivideArrayinSetsofKConsecutiveNumbers.IsPossibleDivide(nums, k));
        }
    }

    public class DivideArrayinSetsofKConsecutiveNumbers
    {
        public static bool IsPossibleDivide(int[] nums, int k)
        {
            if (nums.Length % k != 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var dict = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
            foreach (var num in nums)
            {
                if (!dict.TryGetValue(num, out var value))
                {
                    value = dict[num] = 0;
                }

                dict[num] = value+1;
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length / k; i++)
            {
                int start = dict.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Value >0).Key;
                dict[start]--;
                for (int j = 1; j < k; j++)
                {
                    if (!dict.ContainsKey(start + j) || dict[start + j] < 1)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    dict[start + j]--;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never get people who down vore without writing why

Comment: Not too familiar with c# but isn't the call to FirstOrDefault quite slow, like O(n) implying O(n^2)? I would suggest instead that you don't need a SortedDictionary, instead, just have a dictionary containing the counts, then sort the array and loop over that. That would be O(nlogn). I think there is an O(n) solution if you think about it, as actually I don't think you need to sort anything, simply make the dictionary of counts, start anywhere say at k, and go back until k-t isn't in the dictionary, then k-t+1 must be the start of a sequence, go up, then go back down again, etc.

Comment: I think you are right. The sorting has no meaning here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some C# in accordance with my first suggestion of sorting the array and looping.

```
public bool IsPossibleDivide(int[] nums, int k)
{
    if (nums.Length % k != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    foreach (var num in nums)
    {
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(num, out var value))
        {
            value = dict[num] = 0;
        }

        dict[num] = value+1;
    }
    Array.Sort(nums);

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        var currVal = nums[i];
        if(dict[currVal] > 0) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) 
            {
                if(!dict.ContainsKey(currVal + j))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                dict[currVal + j]--;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is significantly faster, and is `O(nlogn)`, as I say I think there's a `O(n)` solution but I'm not really sure of the exact details and I don't know much C#, probably I could write it in JS if you like.

As I say, this

`int start = dict.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Value >0).Key;`

looks bad to me because once you've done a good number of the consecutive numbers, it might start having to look through a lot of the dict.